# Cast Object array to custom class array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an Object array that I am trying to cast to custom "document" class. I have tried following:

```
 this.documentList = Arrays.copyOf(objectDocumentList, objectDocumentList.length,Document[].class);
```

And

```
 for(int i=0;i<this.objectDocumentList.length;i++){
     this.documentList[i]= (Document) objectDocumentList[i];
 }
```

Comment: And what errors did you got?

Comment: How does you custom Document class look like? You can't just cast here, you should rather implement a constructor in your class and initialize new instances of Document with the data from your array (e.g. in a for-loop like yours).

Comment: It gives error : java.lang.ArrayStoreException.

Comment: @Mumptiz , can you give me an example? My Document class looks like this:      public class Document{  private String header;
private String documentName;
private String documentType;
//getters and setters...
 }

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Document for second option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted my object into string using Gson "toJson" function and then used that String to pass over the network.